# How would I implement an embedded SFTP Server on Openshift

Tags: java, sftp, openshift-enterprise

Background Context:

Due to enterprise limitations, an uncooperative 3rd party vendor, and a lack of internal tools, this approach has been deemed most desirable. I am fully aware that there are easier ways to do this, but that decision is a couple of pay grades away from my hands, and I'm not about to fund new development efforts out of my own pocket.

Problem:
We need to send an internal file to an external vendor. The team responsible for these types of files only transfers with SFTP, while our vendor only accepts files via REST API calls. The idea we came up with (considering the above constraints) was to use our OpenShift environment to host a "middle-man" SFTP server (running from a jar file) that will hit the vendor's API after our team sends it the file.

I have learned that if we want to get SFTP to work with OpenShift we need to set up of our cluster and pods with an ingress/external IP. This looks promising, but due to enterprise bureaucracy, I'm waiting for the OpenShift admins to make the required changes before I can see if this works, and I'm running out of time.

Questions:

1. Is this approach even possible with the technologies involved? Am I on the right track?
2. Are there other configuration options I should be using instead of what I explained above?
3. Are there any clever ways in which an SFTP client can send a file via HTTP request? So instead of running an embedded SFTP server, we could just set up a web service instead (this is what our infrastructure supports and prefers).

References:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-externalip.html

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-service-external-ip.html#configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-service-external-ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally possible, I have done it in the past as well with OpenShift 3.10. The approach to use `externalIPs` is the right way.